# jQuery animate position using calc as value (subtract px from percentage)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Bit of a confusing title but the question is can we take pixels away from a percentage inside `.animate`? I have created an example below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Set the percentage off
  loading();
});

function loading() {
  var num = 0;

  for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {

      $('.follower').animate({
        left: num + "%"
      }, 40, "linear");

      num++;
    }, i * 50);
  };

}
```

```css
.track {
  width: 90%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #999;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.follower {
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #222;
  position: absolute;
  top: 54px;
  left: 100%;
}
.follower:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #222;
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="track">
  <div class="follower"></div>
</div>
```

You can see `.follower` is working as intended but I need that little point above it to start where `.track` starts and to finish where `.track` ends.

So I have to take half of `.follower` width of the percentage it has moved in the jQuery but I cannot find a way to do this. I have looked around and there are ways using `.css` etc but nothing when using `.animate`.

How how we take pixels from a percentage in jQuery when using `.animate`?

Comment: `transform:translateX(-50%);` on `.follower` isn't an option ?

Comment: @Danko You little devil! I have been sitting here for half an hour thinking of a way around this using CSS.... This never popped into my head.  This will do for me but I feel the question deserves an answer. Thank you for that!

Comment: @Ruddy - How about a pure JavaScript solution?

Comment: @chipChocolate.py I would prefer the answer to be in jQuery but I'm always interested in seeing a Javascript solution if it fixes this problem. It could help someone else that runs into this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice answer from @chipChocolate.py ....

Now to add just to your code the only thing you need is substract the `width` of the follower:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Set the percentage off
  loading();
});

function loading() {
  //Create a var to set the value percentage to dismiss
  var rest = ($('.follower').width()*100) / $('.track').width(),
  //Then rest it from the initial value
      num = 0 - (rest/2);
  console.log(rest);
  for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.follower').animate({
        left: num + "%"
      }, 40, "linear");
      num++;
    }, i * 50);
  };
}
```

```css
.track {
  width: 90%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #999;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.follower {
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #222;
  position: absolute;
  top: 54px;
  left: 0;
}
.follower:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #222;
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="track">
  <div class="follower"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: yep @Ruddy maybe just need to handle the rest var on resize ... to avoid some behavior or include it inside the setTimeOut function

Answer (score 1):

1. Instead of using a `for` loop and a `setTimeout()`, you could simply use a `setInterval`.
2. Using `.offsetWidth` you could get the `width` of `.track` in pixels, subtract `.follower`'s `width` from it and animate to the new value.

```js
var follower = document.getElementsByClassName('follower')[0];
var track = document.getElementsByClassName('track')[0];
var tW;
var num = 0;
var percentage = 50;

function loading() {
  var num = 0;
  tW = (percentage * (track.offsetWidth - follower.offsetWidth)) / 100;
  var anim = setInterval(function() {
    follower.style.left = num++ + 'px';
    if (num > tW) {
      clearInterval(anim);
    }
  }, 10);
}
function resizeHandler() {
  tW = (percentage * (track.offsetWidth - follower.offsetWidth)) / 100;
  follower.style.left = tW + 'px';
}
window.onresize = resizeHandler;
loading()
```

```css
.track {
  width: 90%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #999;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
.follower {
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #222;
  position: absolute;
  top: 54px;
  left: 100%;
}
.follower:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #222;
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="track">
  <div class="follower"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah I see, but this will not allow for the size change of the window (making the window smaller when this follower is on the move). I guess I did not state this in the question but I was using a percentage for the track.

Comment: @Ruddy - Yes, I just noticed that. I'm adding a resize handler.

Comment: This seems to glitch for me. When resizing the follower flickers to the end but then goes back to its correct position. Using Chrome on Mac.

Comment: @Ruddy - I've added a variable `percentage`, so now you will be able to animate according to the percentage and not pixels.