# Subtract pixels from percentage width with animate()

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to subtract a value in pixels from a width value that is a percentage using `jQuery.animate()`

```
var fooPerc = 85; // Percent value 
var fooWidth = 40; // pixels to subtract

$(el).animate({
 left: fooPerc - fooWidth;
});
```

The above doesn't work.

So, I tried this

```
$(el).animate({
 left: fooPerc+"%" - fooWidth+"px";
});
```

This doesn't work either.

According to other answers, you can usually use CSS3 `Calc` E.G.

```
height: calc(100% - 18px);
```

But the problem is that `calc` doesn't work with `animate()`.

Is there any clean way I can do this?

Comment: This question was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28172955/jquery-animate-position-using-calc-as-value-subtract-px-from-percentage

Comment: see your solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30618392/jquery-animate-and-css-calc)